# Same Colour graphics as logo

Tags: software-recommendation

Hi everyone I was just wondering if anyone knows of any stock image sites or apps or programs for getting images in the same colours of our logo or a program in which we can edit pictures. Thank you

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? As it is, not really clear what you want, you're asking for 3 different things at once.

Comment: Gimp is a free open source photo editing program. It has an eye dropper tool for checking colors. It also has paint bucket for replacing colors.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has close votes, but I think its an interesting question, just maybe not phrased so well.

It also reminded me of an interesting link... and I suppose answer to the question... [Shutterstock Spectrum](https://www.shutterstock.com/labs/spectrum/?q=forest&hue=18&sort_method=balanced) and I think this could be precisely what the OP is looking for.

http://labs.tineye.com/multicolr/ is also of interest, and only search es creative commons images.

Google has colour filters in Image search of course, but they are not particularly finely tuned!

Answer (score 1):

I used Shutterstock Spectrum and labs.tineye.com, both are amazing site for choosing color combination.
Apart from it, www.colorhexa.com -free tool, guide you about any color and generating matching color palettes for your designs

I hope you would like Colorhexa.